# Send C++ ATL struct into c# application via C++ ATL Fire event

Tags: c#, c++, atl

Now I'm developing C# application with C++ ATL Library. I want to know how to send Struct from C++ to C# via Fire event.

**In ATL C++**

```
  struct ConAccess
  {
   int               action;                
   unsigned long     from,to;               
   char              comment[64];           
   int               reserved[17];          
  };
```

I have on fire event "HRESULT Fire_Server".

**in C#**

I want to receive  array of structure(**ConAccess**) in c# via C++ ATL Fire event.. Thanks a lot...

Comment: You need to covert this data into OLE Automation compatible set of data/parameters, so that this is compatible with event interface method. This can be, for example, a `VARIANT` with array of either arrays of `VARIANTS` with values, or array of byte arrays corresponding to your structures.

Comment: @Roman R,Thank you.. You have any sample code? Because I'm new to C++ ATL..

Comment: @Roman R, I can pass string,double,int via Fire event.. but Array structure only I could not pass...

Comment: `VARIANT` value can hold an array of variants, which in turn could be strings, doubles etc. and values can also be other arrays. On C# side you will be able to unwind that back.

Comment: @Roman R, Thanks a lot.. I'll Check that...